# Is there a way to make axios more verbose?

Tags: android, react-native, axios, okhttp

We're using axios to make requests from our react-native app.

Today we bumped onto an issue where an old Samsung device couldn't reach our servers, and it was because our servers no longer support old TLS. The customer tried reaching our servers through the an **old Samsung browser** the device had, and couldn't. After **they installed Chrome** they were able to **reach our servers without issues**.

If axios returned **a more specific error**, we'd have probably figured out what went wrong, but instead **axios returned a generic 'Network Error'**.

All I'm now asking is this, is there a way to make axios more verbose when it comes to errors, or more specific?

p.s I'm still not sure how to resolve the tsl issue itself either.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know axios on background uses two types of request structure. [HTTP](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js) and [XHR](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js). Since `react-native` does not run on node engine it is probably using XHR and the error you are seeing is related to [this line](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/75c8b3f146aaa8a71f7dca0263686fb1799f8f31/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L81).

```
// Handle low level network errors
request.onerror = function handleError() {
  // Real errors are hidden from us by the browser
  // onerror should only fire if it's a network error
  reject(createError('Network Error', config, null, request));

  // Clean up request
  request = null;
};
```

Although this is not exactly an answer to your question, might give you a start point.